# its not going through the main function to my SOLVE function at all so can someone tell me why... (tried to intilaize the pointers in Main too )

Tags: c

```
    int Longest(char*s, int k, int *start, int * length,int beg,int len)
    {
        int i, j, temp;
        for(i=beg; i<len; i++)
        {
            for(j=1; j<len-i; j++)
            {
                temp=CHECK(s,k,i,j);
                if(temp==1)
                {

                    if(j>*length)
                    {
                        *length=j;
                        *start=i;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        if(*length!=0)
            return 1;

        return 0;
    }
    int Solve(char*s, int k, int * start, int *length)
    {
        int len=strlen(s);
        return (Longest(s,k,start,length,0,len));
    }
    int main()
    {
        int a ;
        int* start1;
        int* length1;
        *length1=0;
        *start1=0;
        a=Solve("abcbca",2,start1,length1);
        printf("%d",a);
        return 1;
    }
```

its not going through the main function to my SOLVE function at all so can someone tell me why.it doesn't really matter right now what the longest and solve functions are since its not even passing through the main function which I really don't understand .. tried using printf in solve function to make sure and apparently its not getting there

Comment: `int* start1;` and `int* length1;` have not been initialised, so dereferencing them is *undefined behaviour*. Make sure you have compiler warnings turned on. You say you did initialise them, but not *how*.

Comment: To get a full answer, you need to post the `Longest` function (or at least a shortened version of it that shows how `start` and `length` are used). See [mcve].

Comment: Ok, in `main` you want `int start=0; int length=0;` The call is `a=Solve("abcbca",2,&start,&length);`

Comment: The code for `CHECK` would be great as well. Better even if you tried to compile your example successfully before posting ..